# While working on Angular 6, I found that there is no way to use constant typescript file for routes path

Tags: angular

e.g. Let's say I have a home component

home.component.html,
home.component.ts

and in home.component.html file, I have anchor link to be routed

```
<a id="routeDashboard" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
```

So what I want is - Instead of hardcoding route path directly here, can we have some constant route path file, i.e. referenced from html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Angular [RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink), your code should be either:

```
<a id="routeDashboard" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
```

or

```
<a id="routeDashboard" routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

Quote from the document:

> If the link is static, you can use the directive as follows: routerLink="/user/bob">link to user component

You can write the links in a constant file or `home.component.ts` file 
home.component.ts

```
links = [
    {id: 'routeDashborad', path: '/dashboard, name: 'Dashboard'},
    {id: 'routeProfile', path: '/profile', name: 'Profile'}
]
```

home.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let link of links">
    <a [id]="link.id" [routerLink]="[link.path]">{{ link.name }}</a>
</div>
```

**Added**:

if we put links in a file constants.ts

```
export class Constants {
    public static links = [{...}]
}
```

You can import it into home.component.ts file:

```
import { Constants } from '/path/to/constants/file';

links = Constants.links;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a doubt - here you have links in ts file. so you are able to do property binding but what if it is not present in home.component.ts file. May be I am using some other file for that, then how it will be binded?

Comment: @AshishKumar See the **Added** block please.